# Are expressions like "How long have you learned" and " I have learned for/since..." incorrect?

Tags: word-choice, present-perfect

Is it incorrect to say sentences like "How long have you learned English?" and "I have learned English for 20 years?" I am primarily asking because two of my grammar reference books claim it isn't incorrect.
In Graham Workman's *Concept Questions and Timelines*, he says that"

> verbs like "work, live, learn, and study" can be used either in the
> present perfect or present perfect continuous with no difference in
> meaning. (page xiii).

Similarly, in A.J. Thomson and A.V. Martinet's *A Practical English Grammar*, fourth edition, they give "learn" as one of the examples of verbs that can be used with either Present Perfect or Present Perfect Continuous with no difference in meaning. Their specific examples (that they say have no difference in meaning) are the questions

> "How long have you learnt English?" and "How long have you been
> learning English?" (page 125)

Upon browsing briefly on the Internet, a lot of people seem to say not only is it incorrect, but the preferred question would be "How long have you studied English?" or  "How long have you been learning English?" Here is a [link](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/how-long-have-you-been-learning-have-you-learnt-english.2785457/) to one such thread. The common theme seems to be that we cannot use "learn" because it implies a sense of finality, that we have finished acquiring information. Addtionally, I had a brief [discussion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/598248/verbs-in-present-perfect-continuous-or-present-perfect-with-no-difference-in-mea?noredirect=1#comment1505696_598248) on another question I posted here recently that seemed to lead me in the same direction.

Digging further, I came across an [old review/critique](https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED289346.pdf) of the aforementioned book *A Practical English Grammar*, where the author claims on page 58 that

> ...the words learn and study while interchangeable in BE, are not so in AE.Consequently, "How long have you learnt English is regarded as incorrect in American usage."

Now, is this really the case? Is it just a BE/UK English and American English difference? Or are these grammar books just plain wrong? I am sincerely confused and looking for answers.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140573/discussion-on-question-by-meepyer-are-expressions-like-how-long-have-you-learne).

Comment: _Learn_ is a resultative, not an action. One doesn't learn for N years; one  **studies** for N years, with the hopeful result that one has learned by studying.

Comment: @JohnLawler People **learn a new language**, and they **learn how to** drive a car. Some people never manage to learn (master) a foreign language nor pass a driving test. **I am learning Polish** seems a perfectly acceptable statement to me, and it uses a progressive construction.

Comment: Indeed, _learning Polish_ is normal. But not _have learned Polish_ for a period of time.  The period of time requires the progressive, because it's still ongoing. But perfective _have learned_ means you're done learning it.

Comment: @JohnLawler My example was to show that *learn* can be used as an ongoing action. “*She's been learning Polish since she found a job there.*” and "*He's been learning to code for six months*” I totally agree that today *have learnt/ed” suggests more strongly an action which is completed, but the same is also valid for any of the verbs listed by AJ Thomason and Martinet, e.g *studied* "*He's studied coding for six months*" Result: Has he given coding up? Does he know how to code now? Or is he still studying it?

Comment: @Mari-LouA — *She's learned Polish since she found a job there* means she has functionally acquired a language in the time since she acquired the job. *He's learned to code for six months* is not idiomatic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*How long have you learned English?* is a very "unusual" utterance that most native speakers would probably just dismiss as "incorrect" (despite the fact that *syntactically*, there's nothing wrong with it).

Some possible intended meanings (most likely first) would normally be phrased as...

> 1: *How long have you **been learning** English?*
> (addressee is assumed to be *still* learning English)

> 2: *How long **ago did you learn** English?*
> (addressee is assumed to **no longer** be learning English)

> 3: *[**For**] how long **did you learn** English?*
> (as #2, but speaker is asking about *duration*, not *when*)

In principle, initial ***for*** in #3 is optional, but the utterance is *slightly* unusual without it. More natural phrasing *without* ***for*** would be...

> 4: *How long **did you spend learning** English?*
> (same meaning as #3, but would *not* normally feature initial ***for***)

---

In all the above, ***learn / learning*** can be replaced by ***study / studying*** without affecting either meaning or idiomacy (but whereas Past Tense ***studied*** is fine in #1, both forms of ***learned / learnt*** would be seen as "peculiar" today<sup>1</sup>).

---

EDIT: Because comments aren't necessarily preserved on ELL, I'll just copy a couple of very useful ones from Prof. emeritus John Lawler...

> Learn is a *resultative*, not an *action*. One doesn't ***learn** for N years*; one ***studies** for N years*, with the hopeful result that one has learned by studying.
> ***learning** Polish* is normal. But not ***have learned** Polish for a period of time*. The period of time requires the progressive, because it's still ongoing. But perfective ***have learned*** means you're done learning it.

---

<sup>1</sup> Just to show that usage has changed over time, here's a Google Books search for the sequence ["learned French for several years"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22learned%20french%20for%20several%22). Three of the four matches that can be read in context are from C19 texts (the other is some obscure Australian magazine from 50 years ago). It *was* once "normal" to use ***learned/learnt*** the same as ***studied***, but it isn't now.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I really appreciate the list of possible meanings. My first choice is the same as yours (#1). I'm just genuinely curious as to why two reputable grammar books include "learn" on a list of interchangeable verbs between the present perfect and present perfect continuous tenses, even though most people say it is "incorrect".

Comment: Has "*you* **have learnt X**” been replaced by “*you* **have learned X**” in British English?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I still often write ***learnt*** rather than ***learned***, but really it's a bit of an affectation today. Don't believe anyone who tells you the difference in orthography reflects a difference in *pronunciation.* It certainly doesn't today (but arguably it *might* have done back in Shakespeare's day).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Peculiar today then, but not necessarily incorrect? So it may be that the books are outdated?

Comment: "incorrect" is a rather pointless term here. I get the impression from your actual *question* text that you've tracked down at least *some* sources labouring under the misapprehension that *as a general principle,* BrE is somehow more biased towards retaining antiquated forms than AmE (if anything, I'd say that ever since Webster's spelling reforms, the *opposite* is the case). Unquestionably, usage changes over time, and at any given *point* in time, some usages are well-known to the natives (because they appear in older texts), but we would rarely or never actually *use* them ourselves.

Comment: That's a fair judgment. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: That's a fair judgement on *your* part! (I'll accept the reputation points! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Don't believe anyone who tells you the difference in orthography reflects a difference in pronunciation. It certainly doesn't today" OK, so which do you claim: that it's pronounced with /d/ even by those who spell it with "t", or vice versa?

Comment: @RosieF: Enunciation will vary by specific speaker and context, as well as *regional* tendencies. It's likely that *on average*, BrE speakers are less likely than AmE speakers to articulate **/d/** (unless preceded by a fully-articulated vowel, as in now-somewhat-"affected" references to ***the learned professor**)*. But you should note that many Brits would often articulate a glottal stop (*assumed* to "represent" /t/), whereas few Americans would do that. I'd say that actually *writing* the /t/ form has unquestionably become just an orthographic affectation over recent decades. Don't do it!

Comment: (I *can* do it sometimes, because I'm British, pushing 70, and I *freely admit* it's an affectation! :)

Comment: I would disagree about the studying part; as a native speaker I learnt English for several years before starting to study it in school, as an engineer I learnt more by years on the job than I did by studying at university, though I have studied for professional exams that's a small part of what you learn.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I (also a Brit) don't perceive "learnt" as an affectation, although I do speak (and write) fairly poshly. Google n-grams suggests "have learned" is 3-4 times more common than "have learnt" in British English today though, so whilst there is definitely a preference for the -ed form, it's not strong enough to really call the -t form archaic https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+learnt%2Chave+learned&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3

Comment: @PeteKirkham: Imho the mere fact that you consistently (and presumably *non-facetiously*) wrote ***learnt*** there shows that you're part of "The Old Guard". See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28we+learnt+how%3Aeng_gb_2019%29%2F%28we+learned+how%3Aeng_gb_2019%29%2C%28we+learnt+how%3Aeng_us_2019%29%2F%28we+learned+how%3Aeng_us_2019%29&year_start=1918&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), which I *think* shows the relative decline in ratio of **-t** compared to **-ed** over the past century (in BrE; it was always rare in AmE). It's not "wrong", but it's "dated".

Comment: @Tristan: Even according to your link, the **-t** spelling in BrE has declined from 1 in 3 to 1 in 4 over just the past 4 decades. And I'd say the *actual* decline is probably faster than that (the chart is affected by corpus misclassifications and the citing of earlier texts, among other factors). Note that your comment is the only current instance of the word ***archaic*** on this page. (Until this comment of mine, I certainly wouldn't have used it! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers its continued use being an affectation seems to require that the use is archaic. It has definitely declined, but I don't think the corpus supports the idea that it is no longer current outside affectation, misclassifications, or citations of earlier texts etc

Comment: @Tristan: My first reference was *it's a **bit of** an affectation today.* I certainly didn't mean to imply there are no "non-facetious" uses ***at all*** today. Nor do I imply any "criticism" of those who still *prefer* to write the **-t** version (it's in the dictionary, and it'll always be understood). But I'd have to say that any current non-native Anglophone ***learners*** who chose to prefer that older orthography for normal contexts would be making a big mistake.

Comment: ...but I will say that I have a *slight* predisposition to interpret the *spoken* utterance *How long has he **learnt** English* as carrying the ***how long ago**?* sense (with an implied initial ***for***), and *How long has he **learned** English* as carrying the ***what duration**?* sense. But that's probably because I *expect* to hear a **-t** or a glottal stop before ***English*** - so if I hear the relatively unexpected **-d**, I assume "less likely sound reflects less likely meaning" ("less likely" because if that's the *intended* sense, the verb ***study*** is much more likely).

Answer (score 3):

I have a paperback copy of A.J. Thomson and A.V. Martinet's, Fourth edition *A Practical English Grammar*, (henceforth PEG), updated in 1985, and in the examples cited by the OP:

> *How long have you learnt English?*
> *How long have you been learning English?*

the authors preface by saying [emphasis in bold, mine]

> **192** Comparison of the present perfect simple and continuous
>
> **A**    **An action which began in the past and is still continuing or has only just finished** can, with certain verbs, be expressed by either the present perfect simple or the present perfect continuous. Verbs which can be used in this way include *expect*, *hope*, learn, *lie*, *live*, *look*, *rain*, *sleep*, *sit*, *snow*, *stand*, *stay*, *study*, *teach*, *wait*, *want*, *work*:
>
> *How long have you learnt English?
>
>   How long have you been learning English?
>
>   He has slept for ten hours.
>
>   He has been sleeping for ten hours.
>
>   It has snowed for a long time.
>
>   It has been snowing for a long time.*

I do agree that the question “How long have you been learning X?” sounds better *today* than its Present Perfect simple equivalent “How long have you learnt X?”, but I do not consider the latter to be ungrammatical. And I  suspect that “I have learnt [language]”, was *always* more idiomatic in British English than in American English.

PEG was first published in 1960, so I searched Google books to find a version prior to 1985 but unfortunately Google does not provide previews of earlier editions. Instead, I found several instances of *I have learnt English* and *I have learnt it* from bilingual dictionaries and grammar publications that appear to support PEG's claim.

From *English Made Easy*, printed in 1909, we have the Present Perfect simple example

[image: Snippet: How long have you learnt English?]

And another example from *Elementary French Grammar* (1911)

[image: Snippet: How long have you learnt it?]

*The Incorporated Linguist* (Vol 21-24) printed in 1982

[image: snippet: though I have learnt Latin]

> *(I had better make it clear at the outset that I have no ax to grind; I am a modern Languages lecturer, and though I have learnt Latin I have never had much enthusiasm for it.)*

Another example, but this time from a work of fiction, *The Rebel Generation* (1928), by Jo van Ammers-Küller

> " To become a doctor! Why you know as well as I do that you must be brought up to it from your childhood. The mere fact of your not having learnt Latin and not having passed any school examinations.…”
>
> “**But I have learnt Latin**,” she said. “**I've been working at it for a year.**”

The 1928 instance, clearly shows the protagonist's studying Latin did not end after a year.

To dispel any doubt whether English allowed its speakers to use the present perfect simple *learn* to express the idea of currently learning a new language which began in the past and continued until the time of speaking, here is an extract from a letter written to David Hume–the Scottish philosopher and historian, by Colonel Edmondstoune, in 1764.

> I wish your time would allow you to come here: you have a great many friends; among the rest a Madame Tronchin, wife to the procureur-general, a virtuous, generous, charitable, good woman. [**She has learned English since** I have been here](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Life_and_Correspondence_of_David_Hume/g7n0DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22good%20woman.%20She%20has%20learned%20English%20since%20I%20have%20been%20here,%20and%20can%20read%E2%80%9D&pg=PA127&printsec=frontcover), and can read your History with as much ease as her own language. Her husband is a man of merit, a man of genius; but knows you only by the translations of your works.

The 1764 citation hints that Madame Tronchin started learning English *when* Colonel Edmondstuone *arrived* and that her learning was on-going.

There is further evidence that the aforementioned construction, which we consider peculiar today, has not totally disappeared. One such example was used in a recent sociological and scientific study:

> Latino-oriented media and news literacy in English must be conscientious of and take into consideration the specific lessons that would be best understood, which will be contingent on the targeted Latinos’ level of education and also their particular language-learning experiences. A monolingual English-speaking Latino **who has learned English since birth** but primarily in informal or non-school settings will not have the same ability as a Latino English-speaker who has had formal education at increasingly higher educational settings.

<sub>*Media Literacy in a Disruptive Media Environment* (2020)</sub>

Also from another study, *American Indian Culture and Research Journal* (1990), we see the usage, mentioned by Thomson and Martinet,  does not seem all that strange all things considered

[image]

> But since one-fifth of the adult American Indian population **has learned English since childhood**, the extent of the language mismatch could be as great as four out of nine. These levels of mismatch assume that American Indians who speak English speak or understand it well, but 7 percent do not speak or understand English well…

Comment: *She has learned English since I have been here* means *In the time that I have been here, she has acquired the English language*. In other words, the learning is done. This usage is normal and does not reflect the usage in question.

Comment: @t  Like it says in PEG the PPS can be used for actions that have only just finished, but there's nothing to suggest that Madame Tronchin actually ***stopped*** **learning** English.

Comment: Hey Mari-Lou, I really appreciate the research! These are some good resources!

Comment: I disagree with your comment, Mari-Lou.  As a UK speaker, that sentence ("_she has learned English since_") certainly implies completion to me.  Obviously one continues learning, but there's a clear suggestion that some suitable definition of "learnt" (i.e. that demonstrated in the following sentence) was completely done during that time.

Comment: @TobySpeight the point I was trying to make was "have learnt/ed [language] for/since” to express an extended period of assimilation or study until the time of speaking *was* acceptable in British English. Today it is not, but it doesn't mean it's ungrammatical as indicated by the title `Are expressions like "How long have you learned" and " I have learned for/since..." incorrect?` The PPS tends to be more ambiguous in meaning than PPC. Does "I have worked there for three years." mean exactly the same as "I've been working there for three years”?  It could or could not.

Comment: Sure - but I don't believe that quote is directly supporting the point you're making, because it's not about a continuing action but a completed one.

Comment: @TobySpeight  "He has lived in Wales all his life". Do we agree that the subject is still living in Wales or maybe he's young and he's changed country? Is the action of living in Wales completed? Likewise the same can be said for "*He's learned Latin since he was a teenager*.” It's neither ungrammatical nor incorrect. It's uncommon, rare, it's less idiomatic,  it's outdated but it remains English.

Comment: The problem is that your examples do not illustrate this "outdated" usage. They illustrate the currently "acceptable" usage.

Comment: @TinfoilHat  I suggest that the 1764 quote hints that Madame Tronchin started learning Eng *when* Colonel Edmondstuone *arrived* and her learning did not stop. The 1928 instance, clearly shows that the  act of learning Latin did not finish after a year; the French grammar book shows the question has an ongoing meaning, see the reply: "I've been learning it..." For if the action had already ended, the reply would surely be *I learnt it for half a year.*